# Need a blank value returned if no subquery results

Tags: sql, oracle, null, subquery

I am trying to look up the most recent value of `gorpaud_pin`, based on the date the record was added to the table.

If there are no record, the entire query returns zero record.

What i need instead is one record with a blank value for `gorpaud_pin`.

```
SELECT spriden_id, 
          spriden_last_name, 
          spriden_first_name, 
          gorpaud_pin 
     FROM spriden 
LEFT JOIN gorpaud A 
       ON spriden_pidm = A.gorpaud_pidm 
      AND A.gorpaud_chg_ind = 'P' 
      AND A.gorpaud_pin IS NOT NULL 
    WHERE spriden_change_ind IS NULL 
      AND spriden_entity_ind = 'P' 
      AND to_char(A.gorpaud_activity_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = 
        (SELECT max(to_char(B.gorpaud_activity_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
           FROM gorpaud B 
          WHERE B.gorpaud_pidm = A.gorpaud_pidm
            AND B.gorpaud_chg_ind = 'P' 
            AND B.gorpaud_pin IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Including gorpaud (aliased as A) in your where clause will make it treat the join as an inner join.  If I"m understanding you correctly, that is probably at least part of the issue.  Try moving that to the ON clause.

Comment: Yes, if I remove references to gorpaud from the where clause, I get a result. But I need the most current value of gorpaud_pin (if it exists). Can the reference to gorpaud in the where clause be moved somewhere else to make it work?

Comment: @Andrew That was my first suggestion, but will it work, regarding the fact that the subquery in that condition refers to the `A` alias?

Comment: This is closer to what I want, but I get a "ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery" error

SELECT spriden_id, 
          spriden_last_name, 
          spriden_first_name, 
          gorpaud_pin
     FROM spriden 
LEFT JOIN gorpaud A 
       ON spriden_pidm = A.gorpaud_pidm 
      AND A.gorpaud_chg_ind = 'P' 
      AND A.gorpaud_pin IS NOT NULL
      AND A.gorpaud_activity_date=(select max(B.gorpaud_activity_date) from gorpaud B where B.gorpaud_pidm=A.gorpaud_pidm)
    WHERE spriden_change_ind IS NULL 
      AND spriden_entity_ind = 'P'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try merging thr gorpaud parts into a separate subquery, and left join to it.  Something like:

```
select
spriden_id, 
          spriden_last_name, 
          spriden_first_name, 
          gorpaud_pin 

FROM
spriden
left outer join
  (select a.* from gorpaud a
   where to_char(A.gorpaud_activity_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = 
    (SELECT max(to_char(B.gorpaud_activity_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
       FROM gorpaud B 
      WHERE B.gorpaud_pidm = A.gorpaud_pidm
        AND B.gorpaud_chg_ind = 'P' 
        AND B.gorpaud_pin IS NOT NULL)) T
on spriden_pidm = t.gorpaud_pm
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle's analytical functions, like `dense_rank`, to do the numbering, and then filter out all records that don't rank 'highest'.

Instead of `dense_rank`, you might also use `rank` or `row_number`. There are subtle differences, and which one you need depends on how you want to handle duplicate rows (with the same date). If that is not an issue, I think you can use either one.

```
SELECT
  spriden_id, 
  spriden_last_name, 
  spriden_first_name
FROM
  (SELECT
    s.spriden_id, 
    s.spriden_last_name, 
    s.spriden_first_name, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY s.spriden_id 
      ORDER BY g.gorpaud_activity_date DESC) AS rank
  FROM spriden s
  LEFT JOIN gorpaud g 
    ON g.gorpaud_pidm = s.spriden_pidm
    AND g.gorpaud_chg_ind = 'P'
    AND g.gorpaud_pin IS NOT NULL)
WHERE
  rank = 1
```

Note that you can safely use `MAX` or `ORDER BY` on date values. You don't need to convert them to chars first. Without the conversion the query may be faster and will be more readable.